# HTML Javascript message input not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
var age1 = 30;
        if(age1 >= 13 && age1 <= 19){
            message = "You are a teenager";
            }else{
                message = "You are not a teenager";
            }
```

This code is pretty self explanatory, but when I run it in html It does not work, I don't know why. It does not give me any of the messages when run in HTML.

Comment: where do you use `message` ?

Comment: what output did you expect?

Comment: Have you tried doing `console.log("text here");` instead of `mesage = "text here"`

Comment: I expected it to output "You are not a teenager" because age1 is not within the 19-13 range.

Comment: @JakeWatson — But your code assigns the string to a variable, it doesn't do anything to output it.

Comment: So you need to log this message. Currently you are only assigning value to the variable. For example `console.log(message)`

Comment: *Warning*: `message` is an implicit global, globals are best avoided 99.9% of the time, and implicit globals are forbidden [in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) which you should be using.

Answer (score 2):

Use console.log to print the message

```js
var age1 = 30;
if (age1 >= 13 && age1 <= 19) {
  message = "You are a teenager";

} else {
  message = "You are not a teenager";

}
console.log(message)
```